# Excel cannot complete this task with available resources. Choose less data or close other application. ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having problem on running the following VBA code on Excel 2010 or later, while it ran just fine on Excel XP. In later versions, a message box with the text "Excel cannot complete this task with available resources. Choose less data or close other application." appears and, on clicking "OK", Excel restarts.

Code:

```
Sub Calibrar()

    Dim PDFFile As String
    Dim XLSFile As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Agendamento").Activate

    XLSFile = Range("W17") & "_" & Range("W19") & "_" & Range("E23") & "_" & "Agendamento" & ".xls"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\PMPA-FS3\DMAE-LabHid-Calibra-Agendamento$\Solicitações\" & Range("W17") & "_" & Range("W19") & "_" & Range("E23") & "_Agendamento" & ".xls"

    PDFFile = Range("W17") & "_" & Range("W19") & "_" & Range("E23") & "_" & Range("E11") & "_" & "Pedido" & ".xls"

    Worksheets("Agendamento").Activate

    Worksheets("Agendamento").Move

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\PMPA-FS3\DMAE-LabHid-Calibra-Agendamento$\Pedidos\" & Range("W17") & "_" & Range("W19") & "_" & Range("E23") & "_" & Range("E11") & "_" & "Pedido" & ".xls"

    Worksheets.PrintOut Preview:=False, Copies:=1, ActivePrinter:="CutePDF Writer on CPW2:", PrToFileName:="", Collate:=False

    Workbooks(XLSFile).Activate

    Worksheets("Controle").Activate

    Workbooks(XLSFile).Sheets("Controle").Move After:=Workbooks(PDFFile).Sheets(1)

    Workbooks(XLSFile).Activate

    Worksheets("Análise Crítica").Activate

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\PMPA-FS3\DMAE-LabHid-Calibra-AnaliseCritica$\" & Range("W15") & "_" & Range("W16") & "_" & Range("E20") & "_Analise Critica" & ".xls"

    ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True

End Sub
```

When I ran this, all files were generated normally, but the message and restarting of Excel are quite annoying.

(EDIT: I forgot to mention that I ran this macro with Task Manager to see how much memory was used and I couldn't see any excessive consumption.)

Any ideas on how I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: One suggestion I would make is to remove `Activate` statements and just work directly with the objects. `Activate` and `Select` statements can eat up unneccesary processing

Comment: Using `Range.Value` instead of just referring to the ranges might help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed suggestions from @ScottHoltzman and @JMichael, and changed my code to this:

```
Sub Calibrar()
'
' Calibrar Macro
' Macro gravada em 20/04/2012 por Lahidro
'
' Atalho do teclado: Ctrl+Shift+P
' Calibrar Macro
' Salva o Pedido de Agendamento da Calibração com a notação Processo+Ramal+hidrometro
'
' Atalho do teclado: Ctrl+Shift+P
'
    Dim PDFFile As String
    Dim XLSFile As String
    Dim processo As String
    Dim ramal As String
    Dim medidor As String
    Dim situacaoPedido As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set planilha = Workbooks("Mod.10.066_Agendamento de Ensaio de Medidor e Planilhas Associadas (revisão 2015.12.04).xls")
    processo = planilha.Worksheets("Agendamento").Range("W17").Value
    ramal = planilha.Worksheets("Agendamento").Range("W19").Value
    medidor = planilha.Worksheets("Agendamento").Range("E23").Value
    situacaoPedido = planilha.Worksheets("Agendamento").Range("E11").Value

    XLSFile = processo & "_" & ramal & "_" & medidor & "_" & "Agendamento" & ".xls"
    planilha.SaveAs Filename:="\\PMPA-FS3\DMAE-LabHid-Calibra-Agendamento$\Solicitações\" & processo & "_" & ramal & "_" & medidor & "_Agendamento" & ".xls"

    PDFFile = processo & "_" & ramal & "_" & medidor & "_" & situacaoPedido & "_" & "Pedido" & ".xls"

    planilha.Worksheets("Agendamento").Move
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\PMPA-FS3\DMAE-LabHid-Calibra-Agendamento$\Pedidos\" & processo & "_" & ramal & "_" & medidor & "_" & situacaoPedido & "_" & "Pedido" & ".xls"
    Worksheets.PrintOut Preview:=False, Copies:=1, ActivePrinter:="CutePDF Writer on CPW2:", PrToFileName:="", Collate:=False

    Workbooks(XLSFile).Sheets("Controle").Move After:=Workbooks(PDFFile).Sheets(1)
    planilha.SaveAs Filename:="\\PMPA-FS3\DMAE-LabHid-Calibra-AnaliseCritica$\" & processo & "_" & ramal & "_" & medidor & "_Analise Critica" & ".xls"
End Sub
```

And it worked. Thank you very much!